# How to schedule a webpage to be executed on daily basis on shared hosting?

Tags: asp.net

I i want to schedule an asp.net page on my hosting, how to achieve it?

for instance, i have a page named myservice.aspx runing on my website.com/myservice.aspx

i want to run this page on every 24 hours. any idea?

Comment: Can we get a bit more information? This doesn't sound like everything you need to give to get the question answered. For instance: Why does it need to run every 24 hours? There are ways to do it, just wanna make sure what's best "for your instance". A little clarification?

Comment: drachenstern, actually i have written a web app, it downoads a zip file from ftp, extarct file from the zip, then parse extracted file. Now i need to run this page to every 24 hour. or once a day. since my webpage will reside on shared hoting like godadday i can schedule the execution of this page. I need a workaround. I found a solution for globa.asax and add a cacheitemremove callback function which seems work fine to me but i have doubt on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use service like onlinecronjobs.com to execute pages.

Comment: Ooh, I need to bookmark that site in case it comes in handy someday.

Comment: Something like [monitor.us](http://monitor.us) might work as well - they will hit your page on a regular basis to make sure it's up and running - probably couldn't get an exact time every day, but you could get close.

Comment: Agreed. I use pingdom.com for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a scheduled task with a little .bat file that just opens the web page.

(Not sure if that's what you mean by "run" the page)

Comment: Unfortunately this looks like it's gonna be the best answer. But there ARE better ways.

Answer (score 0):

i tried onlinecronjobs.com but i got some erros, then i tried setcronjob.com, and everything looks fine but i notice that the free account has an expiration of 31 days, and then I found this one, which looks very good and the free account for 5 jobs looks like it doesn't has any expiration, here is my suggestion:

[http://cronless.com/](http://cronless.com)

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score -2):

I'd rather go with Andy's solution, but I just thought of a weird one:

Set a javascript timer on the page to refresh the page every 24 hours. Then leave the page open in a browser on a computer you'll never log out of.

Comment: Posh, that's just silly. It's going to get closed. I promise.